# Minimum point Polynomial curve

Tags: microsoft-excel

I trying to solve for the minimum value that the x and y components reach in plot (A). I know that you can perform this using IgorPro but I would like to know how to solve for it using Excel.

[image: Plot A]

The plot was constructed using the following data points:

```
110 0.177
115 0.093
120 0.033
125 0.006
130 0.007
135 0.04
140 0.101
145 0.186
150 0.272
```

As you can see there is a minimum x and y data point. However, I want to solve for the minimum point that the polynomial fit reaches.

Comment: Your example is a quadratic function. So just use normal math ([quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)] to solve it?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Maximum-or-Minimum-Value-of-a-Quadratic-Function-Easily

Answer (score 2):

The coordinates
of the minimum of the quadratic trend line 
given its equation in a form `y(x)=a*x^2+b*x+c` 
are calculated as: 
`x=-b/2/a`, `y=c-b^2/4/a`.

The plot for provided data points looks like

[image]

and the trend function equation on the `Excel` graph reads:

```
y=0.0005*x^2-0.1383*x+8.8197
```

, so it appears that `a=0.0005`, `b=-0.1383` and `c=8.8197`.
Let's find the minimum then. Calculations results in:

```
x=138.3, y = -0.743745000.
```

Wait, WHAT? But the trend line clearly looks way higher and all positive!
What's happening?! Let's draw a graph of this function:

[image]

It is shifted down, completely missing the data points! 
And the coordinates of the minimum are correct but for this shifted function,
not the one we need.

The roots of the problem here are hiding in details. 
The equation shown on the graph has coefficients rounded.
Rounded to four decimal places.

```
"Four decimal places would be enough for everyone (c)", right?
```

Apparently, not, especially when `x>1`, not talking about `x>100`s

With 9 decimal places the coefficients are:

```
a=0.000542468, b=-0.138278225, c=8.819723377,
```

the plots looks OK:

[image]

and calculated coordinates of the minimum look reasonable too:

```
x = 127.4528866, y = .007743909.
```

Much better!

But how we can get this more accurate minimum?

Here is a straightforward way, based on matrix functions `MINVERSE()` and `MMULT()`.

Assuming that `X`,`Y` are in `B7:B15`, let's fill a `3x4` matrix in `E7:H9`,

[image]

starting with three cells 
`E7`: `=COUNT(B7:B15)`, `F7`: `=SUM(B7:B15)`, `H7`: `=SUM(C7:C15)`.

Every formula in the next five cells, 
`G7`, `G8`, `G9`, `H8`, `H9`, need 
to be entered as  **array formula** (
type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

`G7`:

```
=SUM(B7:B15^2)
```

`G8`:

```
=SUM(B7:B15^3)
```

`G9`:

```
=SUM(B7:B15^4)
```

`H8`:

```
=SUM(B7:B15*C7:C15)
```

`H9`:

```
=SUM(B7:B15^2*C7:C15)
```

Block `E8:F9` completes a symmetric `3x3` matrix in `E7:G9`:

`E8`:

```
=F7
```

, copy `E8` to fill `E8:F9`.

Select `F11:F13` and enter the following **array formula**

=MMULT(MINVERSE(E7:G9),H7:H9)

[image]

which calculates the desired more accurate values

```
c= 8.81972337662,
b=-0.13827822511,
a= 0.00054246753.
```

As a side note: it is also better 
to convert original `m<=X<=M` range to unit interval `0<=x<=1` first, 
find coordinates of the minimum and then convert `x` back to `X`.